# Calling another class constructor in Java

Tags: java, constructor

I have a mini project that needs to be completed, which is modelling a bank. A bank has branches and each branch is to maintain a list of employees. There are 3 types of employees, Teller, Clerk and Sales.
In my Branch class, i have to created the Staff and then store it.

In my Branch class i am trying to call the Clerk constructor so that it creates the employee i need, and then i want to store this Clerk instance into an arraylist:

```
public void addStaff(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    Clerk clerk = new Clerk(id, name);
}
```

and in my Clerk class is

```
public Clerk(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
```

It doenst seem to be creating the clerk instance
plus instead of calling each instance, clerk1, clerk2 etc, is there a way of using the name being passed in as the instance name?

For the array, i was going to push the instance to it

```
// constructor
public Branch(String branchName) {
    this.branchName = branchName;
    ArrayList<Object> staff = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Comment: Show us how you save it in your array

Comment: Please post a valid [mcve] if you need serious help.

Comment: `Clerk c=  new Clerk("01", "Natalie")` --> I just called the Clerk class constructor.

Comment: That clerk reference is pointed at the new object on the heap in the addStaff method, which immediately goes out of scope and is eligible for garbage collection when you exit the method.  You want to add that reference to a collection in the Branch class.  Add it to your staff List.

Comment: The question here isn't *bad*, but it's missing the critical information about your actual code.  If you include that here, feel free to ping me and I'll reopen it (should it be closed at that time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the new employee in the list you have in Branch. So

1) Modify addStaff, Remove this.id = id, and this.name = name. The Branch doesn't need to have details of the employee.

2) Add the employee to the array you created in the constructor. Branch will be filled with this new Employee.

Result:

```
public void addStaff(String id, String name) {
    Clerk clerk = new Clerk(id, name);
    staff.add(clerk);
}
```

3 and most important) Make all your employees(clerk, teller, sales) extends a generic 'Employee' class and add the construtor just on that class. In this case you change you staff array in branch:

```
private final List<Employee> staff;    

public Branch(String branchName) {
    this.branchName = branchName;
    staff = new ArrayList<Employee>();
}
```

Note the difference. You are creating the staff list inside the constructor only  and then the reference is lost. The staff array should be an attribute of your class. So then you can use in your addStaff Method.

Comment: The employees do inherit from an abstract Employee class, but im abit confused as to what the Employee constructor should look like..parts 1 and 2 i understood...thanks for help

Comment: No problems, just pls accept the answer.
Regarding Employee constructor, it's the exactly same as 'Clerk' class. however in clerk class and others you do:
public Clerk (String id, String name) {
    super(id, name)
}
'super will make use the super class constructor'. and your clerk class should be defined like 'public class Clerk extends Employee'.

Answer (score 0):

You must assign the Clerk instance to the array. An example of code could be

```
public void addStaff(String id, String name) {
this.id = id;
this.name = name;
Clerk clerk = new Clerk(id, name);
this.yourArrayList.add(clerk);
}
```

And also you have to check your constructor.  `ArrayList<Object> staff = new ArrayList<Object>();` if you want to access to the staff content outside of that scope it should be a class attribute.